# Light program (mini MTA?) for system mail (only sending/relay via external server with unattended-upgrades, cron, smartmontools, etc.)

Tags: debian, smtp, mailx, ssmtp, msmtp

I've come across different names in different places: Light MTA, Remote MTA, Smarthost, etc.

Generally, I do not want to install a full-fledged mail server (such as `sendmail`, `postfix`, `exim`), but only send notifications/emails using an existing external ISP/mail provider (such as dismail.de, mailfence.com or others) with `unattended-upgrades`, `cron`, `smartmontools`, my own bash scripts etc from all over the system.

Additionally, it would be ideal if there was support for queuing and retrying (an attempt to resend in the event of being offline or temporarily unreachable by the mail provider)

So far I've found:

- `ssmtp`
- `msmtp`
- `s-nail`
- `nullmailer`
- `dma`
- `esmtp`

But I didn't find any comparison between them.

1. Does anyone know what makes the program stand out from the rest? (positives, negatives, ease of configuration, low resource consumption, etc.)
2. Possibly I missed something and maybe there is another one, better than all those mentioned for Debian?
3. Did I understand correctly that `s-nail` is also an MUA and `bsd-mailx` or `mailutils` is not needed? Maybe others too?

Comment: I'd previously looked for similar and ended up with nullmailer, although I can't recall the other tools I looked at. Having said that, I'd suggest not dismissing Postfix too early. Yes there's probably lots of functionality you'll never use, but its secure, lightweight and well documented. I'm about to deploy something similar and will be using postfix there.

Comment: for what you asking , so deliver systems email, cron, ecc ecc i think `msmtp` and `msmtp-mta` are worth a try, `nullmailer` also can get you what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conducting my research:

From the list given above, message queuing and retrying (for example when the laptop was temporarily offline or the mail server was temporarily down) only support:

- `msmtp`
- `nullmailer`
- `dma`

### msmtp:

I rejected `msmtp` because queuing is not supported natively and requires a workaround through additional overlays:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Msmtp#Using_msmtp_offline

https://gitlab.com/the-foundation/msmtp-cron-sendmail

### nullmailer:

`nullmailer` seemed fine at first, but:

- the documentation is virtually non-existent
- the configuration options are scattered across individual files and do not work as intuitively as their names suggest
- The biggest problem turned out to be the `allmailfrom` option, which simply doesn't work:

  - many email providers reject emails containing `user@host` of the local machine instead of the real email address
  - in other cases, such emails often end up in spam
  - the issue has been reported and has not been fixed since April 2020
    https://github.com/bruceg/nullmailer/issues/72
  - there is a workaround, but personally I am not interested in tricks and workarounds because I am looking for a solution that is elegant and works out of the box
    https://www.atwillys.de/content/linux/force-nullmailer-to-use-a-fixed-from-address/

### dma:

For me the winner is DMA (DragonFly Mail Agent):

- configuration works perfectly and took 3 minutes
- the configuration consists of only two files `/etc/dma/dma.conf` and `/etc/dma/auth.conf` which are intuitive and have option descriptions
- to solve the problem of the `from` field from `nullmailer`, just `MASQUERADE=myaccount@example.com` in the `dma.conf` file and everything works like a charm
- all system notifications work correctly (`Unattended-Upgrades`, `Cron`, `Timeshift`, scripts, etc.)
- it is light, fast and safe (I would like to remind you that it is only used to send e-mails and does not receive e-mails, but many people want this)

Additional information:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/759665/how-to-configure-nullmailer-to-work-with-gmx/759682#759682

https://wiki.mageia.org/en/Dma_Dragonfly_Mail_Agent

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dma

Tested on Debian 11 and LMDE 5

Comment: The deal breaker with DMA (which otherwise looked great) for me was that it apparently only supports Auth Login, not Auth Plain (over SSL).

Answer (score 1):

So your requirements can be summarized as:

- Accepts messages via command-line options or via pipeline into standard input, so scripts and executable programs can send outbound mail
- Can discriminate between messages that should go into local mailbox files (e.g., stdout from the root crontab), and messages that should go to external mail systems for delivery to other mailboxes (e.g., notices to my-alerts@my-domain.com)
- Supports SMTP (and these days probably TLS/SSL encryption) to allow delivery to those external mail systems
- Supports queueing messages locally and re-trying to deliver, in case the "smarthost" is not reachable for a while (there can be a wide variety of reasons for this)

and quite possibly:

- Supports running as a local SMTP daemon for those GUI programs that only know how to make a TCP connection to localhost:25 to send e-mail (and don't know how to invoke an external command)

Mainly the discrimination between messages that should be delivered to local mailbox files vs. external mail systems, and the requirement for queuing and re-trying delivery are going to eliminate a lot of the ultra-simple forwarding agents.  The difference between a forwarding agent that can handle these things and a full MTA is rather small.

I'll echo a remark in a comment that appeared while I was writing this:

A well-configured Postfix will get you all of this.  Most distros have a default config for Postfix that's 99% of what you need, and the other 1% is answering an install-time question or writing a hostname to a config file in the /etc/postfix directory.  (the name of the smarthost that you want to push all your outgoing messages to)

This is a very common need for Linux workstations, which is a very common use case for Linux distros.  So most of them have pre-configured a solution in the MTA they install by default.  For a lot of distros that's Postfix.